# Collection View controller not adding as a subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, subview, uicollectionviewlayout

i have a collection view controller if i add it as sub view as

```
YDCollectionViewCtr *collectionView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"collectionview"];//collectionview
     collectionView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 154, 320, 300);
    collectionView.bussnessdic =bussinessphotoDic;
   [self.navigationController.view addSubview:collectionView.view];
```

or
[self.view addSubview:collectionView.view];

than  just a black screen is added [image: while adding subview]

but when i push it it works perfectly..... I need to add it as subview. Any kind of help will be appreciable
[image: while pushing]

Comment: why do you need to add as childView?

Comment: If you have a UIViewController subclass you shouldn't be manually adding it to your UINavigationController. You need to use the proper push commands to let it manage the stack and view hierarchy on its own. Its a very complicated process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[self addChildViewController: collectionView];`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10671560)

Comment: how did you know my answer was not helping @AbhinavSinghMaurya

Comment: As because you answer does not consist of any kind of explanation

Comment: how did you know my code was not telling everything? @AbhinavSinghMaurya did you really test?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Just replace

```
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:collectionView.view];
```

to

```
[self.view addSubview:collectionView.view];
```

Comment: Let me know if You want to add a customCollectionView to the view of current view controller...
And how r u initialising your customCollectionView...

Comment: I initialised it in first line..i.e from storyboard

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add `collectionView` as a `childViewController`

Comment: Please explain how should i do this

Answer (score 0):

I Faced this issue while working on my App.

you are not calling these methods.

```
[self.CollectionView.collectionViewLayout collectionViewContentSize];
[self.CollectionView reloadData];
```